# Exclude some variables in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-variable

I have a grafana dashboard that have a variable `namespace`, my datasource is Loki. I use this query to get list of namespaces: `label_values(namespace)`, it works well and results are like name1, name2, name3, name4, ..., nameN . but in my dashboard I don't want to see name2 and name4, is there anyway to exclude this 2 name from variable list?

Answer (score 2):

You can [filter variables with regex](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#filter-variables-with-regex).

In your case regex will look like this:

```
/^(?!(?:name2|name4)$)(.+)/
```

Demo and details for that regex can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/yS2nJK/1).

In short, this is a regex that matches (and captures into group #1) anything (`.+`), unless beginning of the string is immediately followed by one of `name2` or `name4` and end of string after that.

More details on matching everything except something specific [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/21363224).